# realloc and pointer to integer comparison issues in c structures and functions

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, casting, warnings

```
typedef struct 
{
    int* data;
    unsigned int len;
}intarr_t;

intarr_result_t intarr_push( intarr_t* ia, int val )
{
    intarr_t* tmp;
    // Warning too few arguments to function ‘realloc’
    tmp = realloc(intarr_t, (ia-> len+1)*sizeof *intarr_t); // problem here..
    ia = tmp;
    ia->data[ia->len+1] = val;
    for (eye = 0; eye < 30; eye++)
    { 
            // Warning passing argument 1 ointarr.c:140:17: error: expected expression before ‘intarr_t’
   tmp = realloc(intarr_t, (ia->len+1)*sizeof(intarr_t));f ‘free’ makes pointer from 
                //integer without a cast
                free(tmp->data[eye]);
                free(tmp);
    } 
}
```

I currently tried writing a program to append a value onto an array passed to me, but these small problems seem to be occurring no matter what I do. Can someone explain to me the underlying problem here and how to remedy it?

I have tried everyone's suggestions, but I am getting this error:

```
intarr.c:140:17: error: expected expression before ‘intarr_t’
   tmp = realloc(intarr_t, (ia->len+1)*sizeof(intarr_t));
                 ^
intarr.c:140:17: error: too few arguments to function ‘realloc’
```

Comment: given this line: tmp = realloc(intarr_t, (ia-> len+1)*sizeof *intarr_t);  The first parameter to realloc is a pointer variable, not a struct type. this part: sizeof *intarr_t will always be 4 (the size of a pointer)  Also, need to check the resulting tmp variable to assure that the realloc was successful I.E. tmp does not contain NULL

Comment: this line: 
intarr_result_t intarr_push( intarr_t* ia, int val )  1) the intarr_result_t is not defined in the presented code.  However the real problem is that the code is expected to return a full intarr_result_t.  That is rarely if ever a good idea.  Much better to return a pointer to an instance (not on the stack) of a intarr_result_t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, it  should be in the following.

```
intarr_result_t intarr_push(intarr_t* ia, int val )
{
    int *tmp;
    tmp = realloc(ia->data, (ia->len+1)* sizeof *ia->data);
    if(tmp)
        ia->data = tmp;
    else {
        free(ia->data);
        exit(-1);//or return something;
    }
    ia->data[ia->len++] = val;//update len
    return something;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I will try your implementaiton, but I am worried it will give me the same error that I have posted in my question at bottom.

Comment: This one is definitely worth trying, I think it fixes the issue.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that your implementation is almost  like mine but has less code. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, I have tried it against mine and as of now I am trying to compare it to see what he did opposed to my wrong syntax.

Comment: Can someone explain to me what the parameters signify in the realloc call.  tmp = realloc(ia->data, (ia->len+1)* sizeof *ia->data);

Comment: It kinda seems that it's multiplying len +1 with size of data which is doubling size?

Comment: @user152573 address of the extended  memory (or NULL when fail) = realloc(address of before expansion , Specifies the size you want to set)

Comment: @user152573 yes, The memory that is secured It will expand in size of one `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`tmp = realloc(intarr_t, (ia-> len+1)*sizeof *intarr_t); // problem here`

change to:

`tmp = realloc(ia->data, ((ia->len)+1)*sizeof *intarr_t); // problem here`

reallok takes a two parameters, the address and the new length

the correct answer is no guarantee, it's just the first thing I saw

sorry, my first answer is incorrect

Comment: Yeah, I realized after trying, but I have tried the one below us and I am getting this warning which I have updated my post with.

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = realloc(intarr_t, (ia->len+1)*sizeof *intarr_t); // problem here..
```

should be

```
tmp = realloc(ia->data, (ia->len+1)*sizeof(intarr_t));
```

and

```
free(tmp->data[eye]);
```

should be

```
free(&(tmp->data[eye]));
```

because you need to take the address of the memory you are freeing.

Comment: I am getting this error with your suggestion and the one above me:

Comment: intarr.c:140:17: error: expected expression before ‘intarr_t’
   tmp = realloc(intarr_t, (ia->len+1)*sizeof(intarr_t));
                 ^
intarr.c:140:17: error: too few arguments to function ‘realloc’